Unsupervised metrics for search engine
I'm the new one to ML, currently writing search engine with different models (tried LSTM, BERT, sentence-transformers) to get sentence embeddings, there are about 2k documents, and don't know how to rate perfomance of each model, because output is the range for each query for each model, but I don't have any labels, so I'm a little bit confused. I'm thinking about creating BOW for every document and analyze query on it, but the point of search engine with nueral network is understanding the context, so I don't know how. Will be very grateful for any ideas! Thanks
